# Install4j Files.log copied in wrong folder

Tags: install4j

the InstallFiles action is a location in temp files, during the installation i changed the ${installer:sys.installationDir} . But Install4j will copy the files.log in the temp location where the installFiles action copied the files.

why? where is my mistake?

Comment: `But Install4j will copy the files.log in the temp location where the installFiles action copied the files.` does not sound like a mistake to me. To change the installation directory, call `context.setInstallationDirectory()` instead of changing the variable.

Comment: the problem is :

i set the context.setInstallationDirectory(path); at the beginning of the installation. Then a few screens later the user can change the path for the installation and i set the the path to context.setInstallationDirectory(UserPath). But at the end of the installation install4j always copy the files.log to the first path. 

why??

Comment: It will move it to whatever installation directory is set at the very end. Maybe you somehow set it back to the first value? Please check the value before the installer exits.

Comment: I think that the files.log will be created in the location where the InstallFiles Action is located?!
At the beginning i set the context.setInstallationDirectory(path) to an temp dir. So all Files i need for the installation are available.
Later the user can change the directory and i set context.setInstallationDirectory(USERPATH). And the end the variable "sys.installationDir" is pointed correctly to USERPATH but the files.log will be created in the temp dir.

i don't get my mistake or is the problem, that the files log will be created in the location of InstallFilesAction??????

Comment: OK, now I see what you are doing. Indeed, the files.log is created by the install files action. The use case "install to temp location, then decide about the actual installation directory" is not supported by install4j. If you want some files to be available immediately, you can add them to the "Custom code & resources" directory.

Comment: and i can access these files before i executed the InstallFilesAction? How? I need to execute an external setup before the InstallFiles Action is done.

Comment: The files on the "Custom code & resources"  tab are automatically extracted to `${installer:sys.resourceDir}` before the installer is started. You can use that variable in all text fields, for example in the "Executable" property of a "Run executable or batch file" action.